# Unable to fill the column from text file

Tags: qt

Here I have used a lineEdit to take the input comma separated value from user.On PushButton clicked it will write to a file(**data.txt**).When we click ReadTable pushButton it should fill the second column of table from file. I am trying to read a text file which is comma separated and trying to fill the second column,but currently unable to do.first column is a fixed column which must not be populated from file.
Here is my code which I have tried so far.

```
void MainWindow::writefile()
{
    QString str = ui->lineEdit->text();
    QString filename = "data.txt";
    QFile file(filename);
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly|QIODevice::Text);
    QTextStream out(&file);
    out<<str<<endl;
    file.close();
}
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
    readfilefortable();
}

void MainWindow::readfilefortable()
{
    QFile file("data.txt");
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return;

    while (!file.atEnd())
    {
        QString line = file.readLine();
        parseline(line);
    }
}
void MainWindow::parseline(QString line)
{
        QList< QStringList > list;
        list << line.split(",");

        ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(list.size());
        ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(2);
        ui->tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QString("Field;Value").split(";"));


        ui->tableWidget->setSortingEnabled( false );

        QString string[5] = { "Sequence" , "Seconds" , "Cost" , "Offer" , "Promotion" };
        for( int i = 4 ; i >= 0 ; --i )
        {
           ui->tableWidget->insertRow( 0 );

           ui->tableWidget->setItem( 0 , 0 , new QTableWidgetItem( string[i] ) );
        }

        ui->tableWidget->setSortingEnabled( true );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some things to consider. You should check the file.open() even when you write the file so:

```
QFile file( filename );
if ( file.open( QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text ) )
{
    QTextStream out( &file );
    out << str << endl;
    file.close();
}
```

I think it would also be easier to just use the write( ... ) function of the QFile class. But this was not part of the question.

There are two main problems in your code I think. You wrote this:

```
    QList< QStringList > list;
    list << line.split( "," );
```

but you need only this:

```
    QStringList list = line.split( "," );
```

You need only a list of strings, not a list of a list of strings.

The second and your main problem is that you never tried to fill up the second column with any data. You just filled up the first column. Also it would be easier to fill up the first column with this code:

```
    QStringList firstColumn = QStringList() << "Sequence" << "Seconds" << "Cost" << "Offer" << "Promotion";
    for ( int i = 0; i < firstColumn.size(); ++i )
    {
       ui->tableWidget->setItem( i, 0, new QTableWidgetItem( firstColumn[ i ] ) );
    }
```

And fill up the second column in same way.

You can also fill up the horizontal headers like this. You don't need to create a string and split it.

```
ui->tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels( QStringList() << "Field" << "Value" );
```

UPDATE:
You can update the second column with your data fomr the file with this.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < listFromFile.size(); ++i )
{
   ui->tableWidget->setItem( i, 1, new QTableWidgetItem( listFromFile[ i ] ) );
}
```

1 is for the second column in your table widget. listFromFile is the variable list in your code.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion when I tried with your firstColumn filling code actually its populate both second and first column.But I want second column to be filled from text.file and first column must remain with fixed fields as I have given in my snapshot.

Comment: @vizhanyolajos- How did you declare the variable listFromFile? I mean how you initialized the variable with the text file,could you please tell the variable declaration for "listFromFile".

Comment: Add to the first line of your void MainWindow::parseline( QString line ) function: QStringList listFromFile = line.split( "," );